# Display property sheets for multiple shell objects

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, shellexecute

I have to display properties window for specified items: folders and files.

For one item displaying properties windows is very easy - just set .lpFile field. But I can't get how to display properties window for several items.

1) Enumerating files in .lpFile like ""file1.txt" "file2.txt"" and so on doesn't work. Even if it works its not applicable, because file list can be too huge.

2) Working via PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE did not bring any results. Can create PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE for single file via ILCreateFromPath, but can't merge several PIDLIST_ABSOLUTEs into one.

Does anyone have any workaround? Any answers will be appreciated

PS: As i've recently understood, PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE is unique-created for concrete unique object. So two or more PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE could not be concatenated. But the question is still actual.

Comment: You are trying to display multiple property windows *at the same time*?  Pretty sure that's not supported.

Comment: Win32 embedded explorer has ability to display properties of several selected items in one properties windows. I want to implement the same.

Comment: Call IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf, pass multiple pidls, and ask for an IContextMenu, then invoke the "properties' verb.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I'm interested in pure WinAPI solution, not MFC, but ty anyway.

Comment: Um, IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf *is* the pure Win32 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf, pass multiple pidls, and ask for an
>   IContextMenu, then invoke the "properties' verb. – Raymond Chen

Thank you, Raymond. It works!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way in delphi:

Get the DataObject from IExplorerBrowser or from clipboard

```
 if (OleGetClipboard(LDataObject) = S_OK) then
    SHMultiFileProperties(LDataObject, 0);
```

Otherwise use the verb 'properties':

```
function TExplorerFrame.DoVerb(Verb: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  LFolderView: IFolderView2;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Supports(FCurrentShellView, IID_IFOLDERVIEW2, LFolderView) then
  begin
    if Verb = 'default' then
      Result := (LFolderView.InvokeVerbOnSelection(nil) = S_OK)
    else
      Result := (LFolderView.InvokeVerbOnSelection(pAnsiChar(@Verb[1])) = S_OK);
  end;
end;
```